# Select sum of column - several variables

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I have at the moment for my select statement:

```
$sql17="SELECT SUM(TotalProfit)-('$sum14','$sum13') AS TotalProfit FROM jwtdriversbank2";
```

I can subtract one variable like this with no problem:

```
$sql17="SELECT SUM(TotalProfit)-'$sum14' AS TotalProfit FROM jwtdriversbank2";
```

But I want to be able to subtract several variables, how can I do that????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$sql17="SELECT SUM(TotalProfit)-'$sum14'-'$sum13' AS TotalProfit FROM jwtdriversbank2";
```

**Be careful when you're constructing SQL queries by injecting variables directly like this though, use prepared statements where possible.**

Comment: Why prepared statements ? There are no parameters in the query, except column names, which are not handled by prepared statements. It would only add extra useless calculations.

Comment: @Virus721 It was more of a general warning, but I've rephrased my answer.

Comment: Thank you that has worked perfectly and i shall take a look at prepared statements but this is just a simple thing really so long as it works that ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum_to_substract = $sum14+$sum13; //add all vars that you want to substract
$sql17="SELECT SUM(TotalProfit)-'$sum_to_substract' AS TotalProfit FROM jwtdriversbank2";
```